# Swift 4 UIButton action in UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimageview, swift4

I am trying to add a delete button as a subview in an image. This is my current structure:

`-> class DesignViewController: UIViewController 
 |
  -> class Sticker: UIImageView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    |
     -> UI button inside the Sticker`

Inside Sticker class I have :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
    button2.backgroundColor = .red
    button2.setTitle("Delete", for: .normal)
    button2.tag = 23
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)        
    self.addSubview(button2)
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")        
}
```

The `buttonAction` is not getting called. 
When I change `self.addSubview(button2)` line to :

```
self.superview?.addSubview(button2)
```

I can see `buttonAction` getting called. However I would like to keep the button inside the Sticker view so that when user moves the sticker, the button moves as a subview with it.

Can anyone please help and let me know how I can keep the button inside Sticker view?

Comment: I think that your are missing `self.userInteractionEnabled = true`. By default `UIImageView` aren't enabled for that.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your comment. I added this line . ``` override init (image: UIImage?) {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } ``` but didnt work

Comment: The buttonAction is not getting called. When I change self.addSubview(button2) line to :

self.superview?.addSubview(button2)
 Why do you want yo change the line??

Comment: Self.superview.addsubview means you are putting it as a sub view of the main view of the viewcontroller

Comment: @Vimal Yes correct. It puts the button into the superview which is DesignViewController class. The reason that I tried with `self.superview?.addSubview(button2)` was to see the buttonAction getting called. TBH I want to keep `self.addSubview(button2)  ` as is

Comment: @Jasmine first change code from touches began to init. A new button is created and added to the imageview everytime the user touches the imageview right now.

Comment: @Jasmine i have a question. You did created a class for imageview named it Sticker. You should have dragged a imageview to viewcontroller in storyboard. Did you change the class of imageview to Sticker?

Answer (score 6):

By default `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of `UIImageView` is set to false. Set it to true and your button will start to respond. You can set it in code as well as in the storyboards.

Also try setting the `clipsToBounds` property of your imageview to true. It will clip your button if it is going outside of the image bounds. That might be one of the reason that your button is not getting touches.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a protocol delegate for button action. This is code example:

```
protocol ButtonDelegate: class {
  func buttonTapped(button: UIButton)
}

class Sticker: UIImageView {

weak var delegate: ButtonDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(button2)
}

lazy var button2: UIButton = {
  let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
  button2.backgroundColor = .red
  button2.setTitle("Delete", for: .normal)
  button2.tag = 23
  button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)        
  return button
}()

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
  guard let delegate = delegate else { return }
  delegate.buttonTapped(button: sender)
}
```

So, now go to your DesignViewControllerl, add your custom imageview class Sticker. Don't forget to do that "imageView.delegate = self". Then in extension add protocol delegate you've created before. Code example:

```
class DesignViewController: UIViewController {

private lazy var sticker: Sticker = {
  let iv = Sticker(frame: view.bounds)
  iv.delegate = self
  return iv
}()

  override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubiew(sticker)
  }

}

extension DesignViewController: ButtonDelegate {

  func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    // input your action here
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I did try your code, however the real problem is buttonAction is not even getting called let alone being able to delegate back to DesignViewController class

Comment: I've edited my code example. This works now. I just forget to write code example where I set delegate in to your custom object. Hope, it will help.